# Numpy: moving tuple mapping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a list of tuple called target as below

```
import itertools
target = list(itertools.product(['a','b','c','d'], repeat = 4))
target = {target[i]: i for i in range(0, len(target))}
print(target)
{('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'): 0,
 ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'): 1,
 ...
 ('d', 'd', 'd', 'c'): 254,
 ('d', 'd', 'd', 'd'): 255}
```

Now, if if I have a list below,

```
source = ['a','b','b','d','a','b','d','c','a','d','b','a','d','c','a'] # only contains 'a', 'b', 'c'
```

Firstly I need construct a list of moving tuple with windows size k, lets say k = 4 here, and the step size d = 2, which looks like

```
[('a','b','b','d'),
('b','d','a','b'),
('a','b','d','c'),
('d','c','a','d'),
('a','d','b','a'),
('b','a','d','c'),
('d','c','a') # remove the last one if its len doest equals to k
]
```

I try to use list comprehension,

```
movingTuple = [(source[i], source[i+1], source[i+2],source[i+3]) for i in range(len(source)//d)]
```

but the last element is wrong. How can I fix this part?

Then, I need to map the movingTuple into the index corresponding to the target dict, which the final result would be like,

```
[
14,
20,
50,
87,
...
187
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close! For the list comprehension, you need to take away 3 from the `len` instead of doing a floor division, and add in your step size:

```py
movingTuple = [(source[i], source[i+1], source[i+2],source[i+3]) for i in range(0,len(source)-3,2)]
```

To generalise this for all step and window sizes:

```py
window_size = 4
step_size = 2
movingTuple = [tuple(source[i+k] for k in range(window_size)) for i in range(0,len(source)-(window_size-1),step_size)]
```

And to index each value into the target `dict`:

```py
result = [target[t] for t in movingTuple]
```

This approach is probably faster than attempting it with `NumPy`.